# bash convert json to string and pass as argument to python script

Tags: python, bash, shell

Hello how can I read a json from filesystem with bash and pass the string as an argument to a python script?
I tried this. But it does not work

```
config=`cat test.json | tr '\n' ' '`
python3 script.py\
    --config $config  \
```

Comment: Just quote the variable, which you should always do unless you have a good reason not to.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29378566/i-just-assigned-a-variable-but-echo-variable-shows-something-else

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why eliminate the newlines?

```
python3 script.py --config "$(<test.json)"
```

Or if you really need them gone,

```
python3 script.py --config "$( tr "\n" ' ' < test.json)"
```

Comment: The important thing is that you've quoted the command substitution.

Comment: Which retains all the whitespace &c, but should not be confused by similar quotes embedded in the data.

Comment: Or `--config "$(jq -c . test.json)"`